# How can I use await in this function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, intptr

How can I make **HookFuncAsync** an async function without causing issues?

```
private delegate IntPtr MouseHookHandler(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private static MouseHookHandler hookHandler;


public static void Install() {
    hookHandler = HookFuncAsync;
    hookID = SetHook(hookHandler);
}


private static IntPtr SetHook(MouseHookHandler proc) {
    using (ProcessModule module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule)
         return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, WinAPI.GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
}


private static IntPtr HookFuncAsync(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0) {
         if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
               await Task.Run(() => doSomething()); // <-- How can I use await here?
    ...
}

[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, MouseHookHandler lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
```

Tried setting the **MouseHookHandler** and **HookFuncAsync** to Task< IntPtr >, compiled fine but crashes on the SetWindowsHookEx because it requires IntPtr not Task< IntPtr >.

Comment: If your method signature doesn't have `async`, then you can't use `await`.

Comment: You can’t. However you can remove the `await` which would mean that `doSomething` runs in the background on a seperate thread. If you need to await it, store the task in a static field and await it outside the hook method. The field should probably be a list of tasks, as a new event may arrive while one task is still running.

Comment: I want to be able to block the HookFuncAsync return until doSomething is finished, is it possible to convert the IntPtr method to a Task<IntPtr> on callback ?

Comment: @fetix That’s not possible, because the handler signature can’t be changed. Even if you would do it, the Windows API doesn’t know about .NET tasks and couldn’t await them anyway. If you want to block the hook why use `Task.Run`, just call `doSomething` directly and it will block.

Comment: Just calling doSomething doesn't work for some reason... Task.Run works but after obfuscation it no longer works.

Comment: Forgot to mention it only works when I add .Wait() at the end

Comment: Is there no way for me to change the HookFuncAsync to Task<IntPtr> and then in the Install() some how alter it so that it can be called ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there no way for me to change the HookFuncAsync to Task and then in the Install() some how alter it so that it can be called?

No.

Windows hook procedures have similar constraints to window procedures (`WNDPROC`). Specifically, they cannot be `async`. They run as part of the user interface, so they must return synchronously and within a very short amount of time.

So, it is not possible to make it `async`, and it is not appropriate to block (`Wait`).

Instead, you can treat this more like an event handler. Specifically, make an intermediate `async void` handler:

```
private static IntPtr HookFuncAsync(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0) {
        if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            OnLeftButtonDown();
    ...
}

private static async void OnLeftButtonDown() => await doSomething();
```

Comment: I need to be able to block/pause mouse clicks so unfortunately this won't work for me, thought it wouldn't be possible but thanks anyways.

Comment: You can set a state variable that directs future invocations to drop other mouse clicks.

Comment: Anyway to drop mouse clicks via the hook ?

Comment: @fetix: I don't remember; the last time I used window hooks was the last millenium.